# Draw pixel image in java

Tags: java, image, draw

I've got an array int[28][28], consisting of numbers 0-255. 0 - black, 255 - white. I need to make an image of 28x28px in size. How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: different types of grey, i guess. between balck and white.

Comment: By "make an image", you mean show an image on screen, save an image to a file, or what?

Comment: Actually, doesn't matter. I just need to see it. Save it would be better, but showing is also good.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use class `BufferedImage`

Comment: I'm trying to find some metods or something to do that, but i just dont find how to conwert this numbers into colours. I mean, there are alot stuff to draw if u have 3 components (RGB), but nothing - if only 1 component.

Comment: Do you need to output the result to the screen or file?

Comment: As i said, doesn't matter. But if i need choose one, i choose file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually the idea is simple enough.  [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) is probably one of the better choices, as it provides a mutable buffer you can write too.  It can be displayed and outputted to disk.

The problem you need to solve is converting the "color" to a "packed `int`" value used by the API.

While this is actually a reasonably common solution, I've watched too many people make simple mistakes when implementing the algorithm, so instead, I make use of the available `Color` class instead.  It's not as "efficient", but I don't think you're trying to produce a solution which needs to run hundreds of frames a second ;)

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[][] pixels = new int[128][128];
for (int y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 128; x++) {
        pixels[y][x] = rnd.nextInt(255);
    }
}

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(128, 128, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
for (int y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 128; x++) {
        Color color = new Color(pixels[y][x], pixels[y][x], pixels[y][x]);
        img.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());
    }
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
try {
    ImageIO.write(img, "png",  new File("SuperDuppa.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```